# file browser : how to always turn on the display thumbnail?

Tags: image, file-browser

When trying to load image from file browser, the default mode always back to 'list' . Everytime i change it to thumbnail, it wail always go back to list mode . This is so annoying. Is there any setting i can make it permanent ?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[Info Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/info/introduction.html)</kbd> --><kbd>File</kbd> --> <kbd>User Preferences</kbd> --> <kbd>File</kbd>  --> <kbd>[Show Thumbnails](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/file.html#save-load)</kbd>

Then <kbd>[Save User Settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/introduction.html#save-user-settings)</kbd>